# autoplay music in ios / js

Tags: javascript, ios, html, canvas

Hi I have HTML5 game on canvas in my page that should start play music when page loading. According IOS new settings it can't start play automatically till user click any button on my screen. May be someone knows how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I guess you've tried adding "autoplay" to your <audio> element ?

Comment: ammm... nope, I'm showing game in iframe, game is not mine, so I don't know how it works inside. I'm just loading this game to my site.

Comment: You need to use HTML5 Audio feature. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/